# How to parse ebay xml response with php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse XML response from ebay for the findingitem api with php. Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<?

$pagenumber = 1;
$keyword = 'iphone';
$entriesperpage = 1;
$ebayusername = 'ebay-username-here';

$response = getFindProducts($keyword, $ebayusername, $entriesperpage);
echo '<div style="display: none;">' . $response . '</div>';

$xmlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $xmlResponse -> searchresult -> item[0] -> title;

function getFindProducts($keyword,$ebayusername,$entriesperpage) {

$xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
$xmlRequest .= '<findItemsAdvancedRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">';
$xmlRequest .= '<keywords>' . $keyword . '</keywords>';
$xmlRequest .= '<itemFilter>';
$xmlRequest .= '<name>Seller</name>';
$xmlRequest .= '<value>' . $ebayusername . '</value>';
$xmlRequest .= '</itemFilter>';
$xmlRequest .= '<paginationInput>';
$xmlRequest .= '<entriesPerPage>' . $entriesperpage . '</entriesPerPage>';
$xmlRequest .= '</paginationInput>';
$xmlRequest .= '</findItemsAdvancedRequest>';

// define our header array for the Shopping API call
$headers = array(
    'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME:' . 'appname-here',
    'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME:findItemsAdvanced'
);

// initialize our curl session
$session  = curl_init(FINDING_API_ENDPOINT);

// set our curl options with the XML request
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if(curl_exec($session) === false){ echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($session); }

// execute the curl request
$responseXML = curl_exec($session);

// close the curl session
curl_close($session);

// return the response XML
return $responseXML;

}

?>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run it, it runs successfully in that it does get the response from ebay, and I can see the product XML structure if I echo the whole thing to the page in the source code.

The problem is with section:

```
$xmlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $xmlResponse -> searchresult -> item[0] -> title;
```

It fails silently without any errors. I do have error reporting turned on.

Any help much appreciated!

--- EDIT ---

The XML code response is structured as follows:

```
<!--?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?-->
<finditemsadvancedresponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>1.13.0</version>
<timestamp>2016-08-18T19:25:06.303Z</timestamp>
<searchresult count="1">
  <item>
    <itemid>123456789</itemid>
    <title>Item Title</title>
    <globalid>EBAY-US</globalid>
    <primarycategory>
      <categoryid>12345</categoryid>
      <categoryname>Category Name</categoryname>
    </primarycategory>
    <galleryurl>Galery URL</galleryurl>
    <viewitemurl>Item URL</viewitemurl>
    <paymentmethod>PayPal</paymentmethod>
    <autopay>false</autopay>
    <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
    <location>Location</location>
    <country>US</country>
    <shippinginfo>
      <shippingservicecost currencyid="USD">0.0</shippingservicecost>
      <shippingtype>Free</shippingtype>
      <shiptolocations>US</shiptolocations>
      <expeditedshipping>true</expeditedshipping>
      <onedayshippingavailable>false</onedayshippingavailable>
      <handlingtime>1</handlingtime>
    </shippinginfo>
    <sellingstatus>
      <currentprice currencyid="USD">15.99</currentprice>
      <convertedcurrentprice currencyid="USD">15.99</convertedcurrentprice>
      <sellingstate>Active</sellingstate>
      <timeleft>P9DT3H29M13S</timeleft></sellingstatus>
      <listinginfo>
        <bestofferenabled>false</bestofferenabled>
        <buyitnowavailable>false</buyitnowavailable>
        <starttime>2015-12-01T22:54:19.000Z</starttime>
        <endtime>2016-08-27T22:54:19.000Z</endtime>
        <listingtype>FixedPrice</listingtype>
        <gift>false</gift>
      </listinginfo>
      <returnsaccepted>true</returnsaccepted>
      <condition>
        <conditionid>3000</conditionid>
        <conditiondisplayname>Used</conditiondisplayname>
      </condition>
      <ismultivariationlisting>false</ismultivariationlisting>
      <topratedlisting>false</topratedlisting>
  </item>
</searchresult>
<paginationoutput>
  <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
  <entriesperpage>1</entriesperpage>
  <totalpages>100</totalpages>
  <totalentries>100</totalentries>
</paginationoutput>
<itemsearchurl>http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sasl=allkillerdeals&amp;_saslop=1&amp;_fss=1&amp;LH_SpecificSeller=1&amp;_nkw=knife&amp;_ddo=1&amp;_ipg=1&amp;_pgn=1</itemsearchurl>
</finditemsadvancedresponse>
```

Comment: You'd have to show the actual/relevant XML. the php by itself is useless without it.

Comment: Can you post what the response looks like?

Comment: You should be able to get the response by running the php with your own ebay credentials. 

I cannot change the xml response, it comes from ebay as is.

Comment: @TK421 just take the example response from Ebay - remove anything personal and post it here. You won't get an answer but asking people to try the request with their own credentials

Comment: We are only asking that you show the response. Hide sensitive info as needed. Possibly the path specified in echo statement is not correct. Don't put the burden on us volunteers to obtain API and run code as is.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When using your provided xml `$response = file_get_contents('ebay.xml');` your code `echo $xmlResponse -> searchresult -> item[0] -> title;` prints as expected `Item Title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally cracked it. After hours of frustration finally figured out that the xml echo path is ***case sensative***. Only happened in the actual script becuase when I copied the xml (for the above example) from the html source code, it showed up all lower case. But the actual returned xml has mixed case in the xml nodes.

So,

```
    echo $xmlResponse -> searchresult -> item[0] -> title;
```

needed to be:

```
    echo $xmlResponse -> searchResult -> item[0] -> title;
```

Comment: But your posted XML has `searchresult` all lowercase and not camelcase.

Comment: It does... I copied it from the html source code on the page which made it all lower case. It wasn't until I printed it into a textarea and compared it with the response structure from the ebay api documentation that I realized it was camelcase.